# Vaadin: Difference between setValue and setInternalValue

Tags: java, vaadin

Im currently developing a vaadin application and i wondered where there is the difference between the so called "internal value" (setInternalValue()-Method) and "value" (setValue()-Method) of display components like a label in vaadin.

I want to know to avoid problems in the future and i didnt find a solution or any good documentation.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Are you asking for the difference between `setConvertedValue()` vs `setValue()`?

Comment: No, im asking for the difference between setValue() and setInternalValue()

Comment: As far as I know and as per the [API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setInternalValue-T-), `setInternalValue` does not trigger `ValueChangeEvents`. I've used it only once when developing a _pagination_ component to set the value of an input to the max/min when the user manually entered an invalid value, without triggering a new value change event. If I'm not mistaking you could end in an endless loop if for example you call `setValue` of an input from its `ValueChangeListener` :-)

Comment: Aside from the trigger: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setInternalValue-T-